# regex to match 3 parts from a given string

Tags: php, regex

Example input:

```
hjkhwe5boijdfg
```

I need to split this into 3 variables as below:

1. hjkhwe5 (any length, always ends in some number (can be any number))
2. b (always a single letter, can be any letter)
3. oijdfg (everything remaining at the
   end, numbers or letters in any combination)

I've got the PHP `preg_match` all setup but have no idea how to do this complex regex. Could someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with:

```
$str = 'hjkhwe5boijdfg';
preg_match("/^([a-z]+\d+)([a-z])(.*)$/", $str, $m);
print_r($m);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => hjkhwe5boijdfg
    [1] => hjkhwe5
    [2] => b
    [3] => oijdfg
)
```

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
  (         : 1rst group
    [a-z]+  : 1 or more letters
    \d+     : followed by 1 or more digit
  )         : end of group 1
  (         : 2nd group
    [a-z]   : 1 letter
  )         : end group 2
  (         : 3rd group
    .*      : any number of any char
  )         : end group 3
$
```

Comment: Coda was faster, but that explanation just nailed it.  I now understand regex!  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_match as:

```
$str = 'hjkhwe5boijdfg';
if(preg_match('/^(\D*\d+)(\w)(.*)$/',$str,$m)) {
        // $m[1] has part 1, $m[2] has part 2 and $m[3] has part 3.
}
```

[See it](http://www.ideone.com/ak0EJ)